# Как в tkinter combobox убрать выделение выбранного текста?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk

Я пишу проект на питоне с использованием графического интерфейса. Для выполнения части задач мне необходимо воспользоваться выпадающим списком `Combobox` из библиотеки tkinter, но при работе с этим виджетом у меня возникла проблема: когда ты выбираешь элемент из списка, он автоматически выделяется голубым цветом. Как можно убрать такое выделение?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
combo_list_1 = ttk.Combobox(root, justify=CENTER, state='readonly', values=('нет', '20 см', '40 см', '60 см', '80 см', '100 см', '120 см', '140 см', '160 см', '180 см', '200 см', '220 см', '240 см', '260 см', '280 см', '300 см'))
combo_list_1.current(0)
combo_list_1.grid()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно при срабатывании события изменения выбранного значения убирать выделение:

```
def on_change(event):
    combo_list_1.select_clear()


combo_list_1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_change)
```